# (mis)Understanding the reduced $\chi^2$ statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, chi-squared

In chapter 8 of the book "Measurements and their Uncertainties" by Huge and Hase, they discuss the reduced chi squared statistic.

They define it as

$$
\chi^2_v = \frac{\chi_{\text{min}}^2}{v}
$$

where $v$ is the number of degrees of freedom, and $\chi_{\text{min}}^2$ is the lowest mean square error of some data fitted to some model.

They write

> In Section 8.4 we discussed how one would
>   not be surprised if the observed value of χ2 was within 2σ of the mean for a min
>   good fit, and that the null hypothesis should only be questioned if the value of
>   χ2 was larger than, say, 3σ from the mean. As the standard deviation of the min
>   χ 2 distribution depends on ν , the confidence limits for χν2 also depend on ν . In Fig. 8.5 the values of χν2 calculated at ν + σ, ν + 2σ, and ν + 3σ are plotted as a function of the number of degrees of freedom. Recall that for a Gaussian distribution these intervals correspond to the 68%, 95% and 99.7% confidence limits. The 3σ confidence limit of χν2 is tabulated for several values of ν in Table 8.1.

with the following being a capture of Fig. 8.5 and Table 8.1.

[image]

However, I don't get how the graphs and the tables are produced.

Naively, looking at the label of the graph one would think that

$$
\chi^2_v = 100+3\cdot 0.997 \neq 1.4 
$$

for $v=100$.

Moreover, I don't see how you can compute a meaningful value for $\chi^2_v$ without knowing $\chi_{\text{min}}^2$.

I've tried, unsuccessfully, to reproduce table 8.1, but I don't understand how it's computed

```
import scipy.stats as st
v=100

# mean chi2v + chi2v value at 3 sigma
1+st.chi2.ppf(0.997,v)

# 144???

# maybe we should divide by v?
(1+st.chi2.ppf(0.997,v))/v
# 1.44 - seems right

# but that doesn't work for v=5 giving us 3.79/=2.9
```